# Highlighting line which are not correctly formated [Eclipse]

Tags: eclipse, coding-style, eclipse-plugin

So I have some formatting rule to follow, such as :

```
Space on each side of operator (*, =, +, %, etc)
No space at the end of a line
No more than 80 chars per line
```

Is there a way to highlight in red line containing formating error?
The eclipse auto-formating tool is no good because either :

It will change to many line (old code not written by me)
or it won't (only my code)

Because I must follow some "colorfull" guideline :

```
You must change formating error relative to operators in old code but nothing else
Your code must be correctly formated.
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can select which lines of code you want to format.  The Eclipse formatting tool doesn't have to run across the entire file.  To do this: select the lines you want to format, then press Ctrl-Shift-F.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/).

You'll need to configure it with just the rules that you need (the default configuration is very strict, so create a new one with just the rules you care about).

This will highlight all lines with formatting issues. I don't think it's possible to ignore old code using the plugin.

Answer (score -1):

Talk to whoever created that coding guideline. It does not make sense in the long run, because editing code in Eclipse will always apply all current formatting rules (which violates that guideline) or none, if you disable the formatter (which leads to you writing bad code).

If there is really no way around that guideline, then you should split your workflow into 2 phases: Reformat *all* existing code one time to fulfill that operator guideline. You may use any tool you like, even just a regular expression search and replace might be fine.

After that has been done, configure Eclipse to auto-format only changed lines, but always apply all formattings to each changed line. There is no good reason to not re-format the other 75 characters in an existing line of code, if you already touched 5 characters of it.